# adding magento custom attributes on the frontend

Tags: php, magento

Ok! I am working on this magento project from last 2 weeks. This is my first magento application.

I have added Some new attributes in the back-end for of magento Products like this....

`Backend -> Catalog -> Manage Products -> 'Selected one product' -> General setting -> Create New Attribute`

Suppose I added `locking`(Attribute Code) Attribute here in back-end now I want to show this attribute at the front-end on the product landing page.

I tried call like this this in
`frontend\mgstheme\luxury\template\catalog/product/view/description.phtml`

```
<?php echo $_product->getLocking(); ?>
```

but it is not visible

Am I doing it wrong?If so Please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, for each product attribute which you want to use on the product page or category page, you will have tell Magento whether or not they should be made available.

To do this, find the attribute under Magento `Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Attributes` . Then under frontend properties, near the bottom, you will find options for: `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` and `Used in Product Listing`. Set its value to YES.

These will allow you to display the attribute on the product page and category page respectively.

Comment: so after i have done this changes do i have to call attribute like `<?php echo $_product->getLocking(); ?>` right?

Comment: Cool! I'll try n let you know. Thanks